# How can I log out from my Stack Overflow account?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, user-experience, logout

I just want to log out.

I am not sure what else to write here to meet quality requirements. Is it not important for your users to be able to log out? What if they have multiple accounts? Many questions... few answers...

Comment: member for 6 years and only just trying to log out?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I can't recall ever logging out in my 12 years. It probably did happen at some point.

Answer (score 10):

You can log out by clicking the top rightmost icon and logging out of the relevant community.

[image: StackOverflow logout button]